# File output deletes all the content

Tags: file-io, java-io

I am trying to make a program which removes text from a file. The text to remove and the file path are provided as command line arguments. Everything goes fine, but when I open the file after the program has finished running, it's all empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Remove {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("usage : java Remove stringToRemove filePath");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String stringToReplace = args[0];
    String path = args[1];
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("No such file exists!");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);

    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String currentLine = input.nextLine();
        currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll(stringToReplace, "");
        output.println(currentLine);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();

    System.out.println("Operation Successful");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file for writing clears the file, so if the input and output files are the same, then the input will be cleared and nothing will happen because there are no lines.